# Chakra UI and NextJS hydration issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui, hydration

I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <a> in <div>.
```

I currently have the following code snippet:

```
return (
    <Flex bg='tomato' p={4} ml={'auto'}>
      <Box ml={'auto'}>{body}</Box>
    </Flex>
);
```

where,

```
body = (
      <>
        <Link as={NextLink} href='/login' mr={2}>
          login
        </Link>
        <Link as={NextLink} href='/register' mr={2}>
          register
        </Link>
      </>
);
```

I am currently following the latest ChakraUI docs on this page: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/link

[image: Chakra-UI-docs]

where they mentioned about the hydration issue. However, following their example still doesn't solve the problem.

pages/app.tsx:

```
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import theme from '../theme';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

index.tsx:

```
const Index = () => {
  const [{ data }] = useQuery({ query: PostsDocument });
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <div>Hello world</div>
      <br />
      {!data ? (
        <div>loading...</div>
      ) : (
        data.posts.map((p) => <div key={p.id}>{p.title}</div>)
      )}
    </>
  );
};

// NOTE DEFAULT is SSR=false
export default withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient, { ssr: true })(Index);
```

Inside the  component I have the above links.

Comment: Are you using the `app` directory of Next.js?

Comment: Not too familiar with `app` so not 100% sure, but i would assume so as I have nextjs version at latest and i just created everything today.

Comment: Do you have files like `page.tsx`, `layout.tsx`...? If so you are using the `app` directory.

Comment: My folder structure contains `pages/_app.tsx` and `pages/index.tsx` etc..
I don't have a `layout.tsx`.
Edited my post to include how `_app.tsx` looks like

Answer (score 1):

Have you sorted the hydration issue out yet? I had a similar issue even after following the chakra-ui docs and suggestions on nextjs link and chakra Link usage, but turns out my issue was entirely something else.

You might want to check your NavBar implementation.

I was using checks like 'typeof window !== "undefined"' in my rendering logic to manage what is rendered on the NavBar.
Apparently, using browser-only APIs like window or localStorage in the rendering logic can trigger a hydration error.

I had to eventually manage my situation with useState and useEffect hooks and they worked out.

You can check here for the official Nextjs response to common causes of hydration errors and possible ways to solve them:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install `@chakra-ui/next-js` for Links.

Make sure you are importing Link from NextJs and Chakra UI seperately.

```js
import { Link } from '@chakra-ui/next-js'
import NextLink from 'next/link'
```

The NextLink from `next/link` will be used for the `as` property, and you will use the `<Link>` tag from Chakra.

The final working code should look like this

```
import { Box, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { Link } from '@chakra-ui/next-js'
import NextLink from 'next/link'


const test = () => {
  return (
  <Flex bg="tomato" p={4} ml={'auto'}>
    <Box ml={'auto'}>
      {/* The Box Component */}
      <Link as={NextLink} href="/login" mr={2}>
        login
      </Link>
      <Link as={NextLink} href="/register" mr={2}>
        register
      </Link>

    </Box>
  </Flex>
  )
}

export default test
```

Comment: I changed my import to `import { Link } from '@chakra-ui/next-js'` but it still throws the same error. Im only facing this issue when i set ssr = true.

Comment: In the example above you can omit `as={NextLink}` when using Link from `@chakra-ui/next-js`. It was required with Link imported from `@chakra-ui/react`.
More https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide#chakra-ui-with-nextjs-link